# How to get price data for a redeem without using chainlink

Tags: contract-design, stablecoins

Trying to make a ecosystem where you have two tokens (Token X, Token Y) Token X can be minted for $1 worth of Token Y burned. And Token X can be redeemed for $1 worth of Token Y. How would I do this in solidity without using a data feed like chainlink? I'm a horrible coder so advice would be appreciated lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to take the token outside your solidity project's world, there is no way of getting the price of the token without using an oracle service.

Comment: What if I used a twap over like a minute

Comment: I am not sure whether that can be very successful. Go through the failures of all algorithmic stable coins in existence to understand what not to do. I am no expert to comment further on it. Just know that oracle would give you the accurate value that you need when dealing with financial stuff.